# Simulate a SNMP agent with dummy data

Tags: python, simulation, snmp, agent

I want to simulate a simple device with like, three OIDs. I don't have a MIB yet, only the OIDs. I basically want to recreate the device in Python for testing purposes. Therefore I created a simple agent with pysnmp:

```
from pysnmp.hlapi import SnmpEngine
from pysnmp.entity import engine, config
from pysnmp.entity.rfc3413 import cmdrsp, context
from pysnmp.carrier.asynsock.dgram import udp
from pysnmp.smi import instrum
from pysnmp.proto.api import v2c

snmpEngine = SnmpEngine()

config.addSocketTransport(
    snmpEngine,
    udp.domainName,
    udp.UdpTransport().openServerMode(('127.0.0.1', 161))
)
    
config.addV3User(
    snmpEngine, 'goldrush'
)

config.addVacmUser(snmpEngine, 3, 'usr-md5-des', 'authPriv',
                    (1, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4), (1, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4))

snmpContext = context.SnmpContext(snmpEngine)

class EchoMibInstrumController(instrum.AbstractMibInstrumController):
    def readVars(self, vars, acInfo=(None, None)):
        return vars

snmpContext.registerContextName(
    v2c.OctetString('my-context'),  # Context Name
    EchoMibInstrumController()  # Management Instrumentation
)

cmdrsp.GetCommandResponder(snmpEngine, snmpContext)
snmpEngine.transportDispatcher.jobStarted(1)
try:
    snmpEngine.transportDispatcher.runDispatcher()
except:
    snmpEngine.transportDispatcher.closeDispatcher()
    raise
```

But I don't understand where I can the feed the dummy data into it - when I issue a GET-Request, I only get the answer that this OID I ask for doesn't exist on the agent.
I read through many tutorials, but often they use MIBs, which I can't get my fingers on at the moment. I never see them add any values..

The pysnmp doc is down so I can't get any real info. Can someone give me hint how to create a simple agent?

Comment: From the lack of answers you can gather this is not a trivial effort. If you are versed in SNMP, it will be man-weeks (1 or 2) to create this using open-source  from scratch. There are commercial SNMP simulators (ours for example) that might give you the ROI that's better than that.

Comment: Wow, seems like snmp isn't that simple at all. I'm currently ty to implement my idea with snmpd and an smp pass-through to my python script.

Comment: This is a 15 minute exercise with our simulator, once you have defined your MIB. What you get with that effort is the ability to change your data at runtime, reset your simulation at any point, trivial scalability in the quantitative (number of agents) and qualitative direction (MIB objects), etc.